# DML operation against synonym oracle

Tags: oracle, dml

I have been reading the [GoldenGate 11g R2 installation guide](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15881_01/doc.104/gg_ora_inst_v104.pdf) and it states:

> **Non-supported objects and operations in Oracle DML:**
>
> *[...]
> Synonyms
> [...]*

But I see in the next section that DDL operations are supported, so `CREATE`, `ALTER`, etc...

So, what is exactly a DML operation against a synonym and how is it not supported?

Comment: Google is quick! https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2389858&tstart=0

Comment: Indeed!! I posted it in both, let's see who's the fastest... ;)

Answer (score 1):

From reading the documentation, it looks like DML on a synonym for a normal object will not be replicated. For example, you have a table called `FOO` & a synonym called `BAR` that points to `FOO`. An `INSERT` into `FOO` will succeed, but an `INSERT` into `BAR` will not, as it is a synonym for another table & not a real base table.

Test this in your dev environment to verify.

Comment: Tested, and it works! I did several INSERT, UPDATE against the source, and they were replied in the target, so I still don't have a clue of what they mean by DML against synonym...